# how to load graph after loading other data

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, html, jquery-ui

**I'm using rails 3.2.1**

My page is divided into 5 parts

**part-1 header

part-2 div area

part-3 graph part

part-4 data in tabular format

part-5 footer**

Now my problem is that graph take too much time to upload.
Due to which this page take too much time to load.

Please tell me any method so that **my graph load in the last** but other data will display.

Comment: I take that you mean "download" instead of "upload"? What technology are you using to render the graph?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that the graph data is taking too long to download, then you'll need to download it separately with an AJAX call instead of including it directly in the page. Something like:

```
$.getJSON("/url/to/your/data", function(data){$.jqplot('chart1', data)});
```

...which you'll have to support on the server by making `/url/to/your/data` provide the same graph data that you currently embed in the page. That code will start downloading and then rendering the graph data separately from the rest of the page.

If that causes problems with the DOM not quite being ready (not sure why it would), then wrap your call so that it only happens when the doc is fully rendered:

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON("/url/to/your/data", function(data){$.jqplot('chart1', data)});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you can do is to call the function that draws the graph when condition is true. For example:

```
(function isMyDataLoaded(){

    //if the table is rendered
    if($('#TableData').length==0){
         setTimeout(isMyDataLoaded,100);    
    }else{
          DrawGraphFunction();    
    }
 })();
```

Note: I do not know your logic, so you can use other condition.

Comment: how I check if my other data is rendered or not ?

Comment: When, the other data is rendered, he renders table with it - what I have used is to check if there is table with such ID - $(#TableID).length

Comment: there is nothing in jquery to find what you say.

Comment: @manishnautiyal That's just a ordinary recursive function - you can add multiple conditions in the if statement as well. For example:
if($('#TableData1').length==0|$('#TableData2').length==0...) do not render the graph - wait 100 milliseconds.. Have you got the idea?